# Soundcloud explore section

Tags: api, soundcloud

I am exploring soundcloud's API, and I have seen that thought through the web you can access [explore sections](https://soundcloud.com/explore), I haven't found any docs that help you to do so through the API.

Anyone has tried this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

soundcloud explore section uses new API calls that are still not documented. same with stream.
but you can check under the hood (in chrome developer tools -> network tab) to find new api calls.

for example, main explore section points to `https://api.soundcloud.com/explore/sounds/category?limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1`
and rock section points to
`https://api.soundcloud.com/explore/sounds/category/rock?limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1`

p.s. don't forget to include your client id in the calls

Comment: well, you'll probably need to extend the library with missing calls like the one above.

Comment: Ok, I was using the oficial python-soundcloud plugin. The bad thing is that they are appending .json to all the urls I write. I have reported the bug [#21](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/issues/25).

Meanwhile, I will implement my own call for this.

Answer (score 2):

The API has been updated. You can use following URL to access the explore section (based on @cucko's reply):

`https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/explore/categories?limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1`

With client id in the call:

`https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/explore/categories?limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID`

Answer (score 1):

The API has been updated.You can use following URL

`https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/charts?kind=top&genre=soundcloud%3Agenres%3Aall-music&limit=20&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID`

Comment: Thank you. Noticed it wasn't working anymore but couldn't find any information. How did you find out?